# Ghostscript Skip Box Dialog

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

My problem is not with `Ghostscript`, its works fine.
The problem is that when I try to print, Ghostscipt process call to `Print Driver` and a confirmation is needed.

I have to print without box print dialog, similar to called `Quick Print` on Office package.

My print model is `HP Professional P1102`, Operative System `W7`, printer is connected from USB.
I am using next command on Windows cmd:

```
gswin64.exe -dNOSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\\spool" "\\pdf_name.pdf"
```

Somebody have suggestions?

Thanks for all

Comment: You are going to have to be rather more specific. If you print to a named printer then you should not see a dialog box **unless** you specify QueryUser. What precise command line are you giving to Ghostscript ?

Comment: gswin64.exe -dNOSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\spool" "\pdf_name.pdf"

Comment: Well, there's your problem right there '-sOutputFile="\spool"'. How is mswinpr2 supposed to know whcih printer to send it to without prompting you with a dialog ? If you want to print to the WIndows default printer you can do -dQueryUser=2, if you want to print to a specific printer then you need to set OutputFile appropriately, eg -sOutputFile="%printer%My Printer" This is documented in ghostpdl/doc/devices.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
gswin64.exe -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\\\\spool\printername" "C:\pdf_name.pdf"
```

I tried this and it works without any prompt.
The printer name is after the \\spool\ string.